# How can I run the same code throughout my Perl scripts with as little code duplication as possible?

Tags: function, class, perl, subclass, code-duplication

I have a subroutine, `csay`, that's defined in a Perl class (package). There are several subclasses of it that run that subroutine often and throughout themselves. Its behaviour depends on a few variables (most of which must be given as arguments), one of which is constant within any lexical scope (`$debug_level`). I'm trying to avoid duplicating code as much as possible, including having to pass the "constant" variable as an argument every single time or prefixing every usage with `$self->`.

I'm not against using compile-time substitution (if such a thing exists in Perl), but I'd like to avoid using instances (`bless`ing hashes, etc) if possible. See below for an example of what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

```
package SystemManager::Action::Generic;

sub csay($self, $cur_debug_level, $min_debug_level, $message) {
    if ($cur_debug_level >= $min_debug_level) { print("$message\n"); }
}

sub prepare_system($self)...

package SystemManager::Action::Backup;
use parent "SystemManager::Action::Generic";

sub backup_system($self,$debug_level,@files) {
    $self->csay($debug_level, 1, "Starting backup");
    $self->prepare_system();
    $self->csay($debug_level, 1, "Iterating through files");
    for my $file in (@files) {
        $self->csay($debug_level, 2, "Processing $file");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`csay` doesn't *need* to be part of the same class; the most important part is to not have to specify `$debug_level` as an argument every single time.

Comment: Why don't you want to prefix every usage with `$self->`? That seems like the right pattern to me: if `csay` depends on context from the object that's calling it, then it's really a *method* rather than a *subroutine*. No?

Comment: It's important to understand that every language has common idioms, and if you're following those idioms then you're necessarily going to be "duplicating" them. This isn't what people mean when they talk about eliminating code duplication. You don't want to duplicate actual *logic* in a bunch of places, but writing `$self->csay(...)` everywhere that you want to call `csay` is a common pattern, and is not actually "duplication" in the sense that you should be avoiding.

Comment: @ruakh It's mostly a preference, but doing it isn't a deal breaker. I didn't realize that package/"class" subroutines were also called methods but I think you're right, however `csay` doesn't require any information that couldn't be provided as an argument. I'm using classes and subclasses for greater flexibility down the road.

Comment: Re "*I'm using classes and subclasses for greater flexibility down the road.*", Your question specifically asked not to use objects, which would actually be quite a reasonable solution to the problem. You also said you didn't want to use an invocant, which precludes classes and objects.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to clarify your question. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: @ikegami I'm trying to avoid instantiating/blessing objects, but "class" methods and the like are fine. Invocants are fine too, it's just that if I could paste `use MyPackage qw(csay)` once instead of pasting `$self->` hundreds of times that would be preferable.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Please see the updated question.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're after and what exact restrictions you have in mind.   If you don't want to have to pass around the same ol' constant then write a separate package (like a header file) just for constants and `use` that where those are needed. For example. Or use object's attribute, specially if the "constant" depends on circumstances. Why are you trying to "_avoid ... objects_"?  If that is so, then don't have a class but just a normal library (package) -- but if you think inheritance & Co will simplify your life later then you do need them.  A bit more detail please?

Comment: Thank you for adding specifics.  The constants (`$debug_level` in this example) ... is it set once for the whole run? Or can it be different across the program (in different classes, sub-processes, etc)?

Comment: @zdim I'm not sure what you mean by "whole run". It's specified by the user via @ARGV in the external script that calls `SystemManager::Action::Backup->backup_system`. It's likely constant in each execution of the external script, but will differ between executions.

Comment: That's what I meant, yes -- whether that "constant" can change during a run or not. So it's set at startup ... but then you do say "likely constant" though?  So is it supposed to be possible to change it during the run?

Comment: Also, may constants ever end up needing differenet values for different objects? Since you do plan on using objects down the line ... (a good idea!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [the answer by Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68681573/459640), you could use an exportable `our` variable:

```
package SystemManager::Action::Generic;
our $cur_debug_level = 0;
our @EXPORT = qw($cur_debug_level); # or @EXPORT_OK to export explicitly only

sub csay($self, $min_debug_level, $message) {
    if ($cur_debug_level >= $min_debug_level) { print("$message\n"); }
}
    
package SystemManager::Action::Backup;
use parent "SystemManager::Action::Generic";

sub backup_system($self,@files) {
    $self->csay(1, "Starting backup");
    $self->prepare_system();
    $self->csay(1, "Iterating through files");
    for my $file in (@files) {
        $self->csay(2, "Processing $file");
        ...
    }
    ...
}

package main;
use SystemManager::Action::Backup;
$cur_debug_level = 2;
my $backup = Backup->new();
$backup->backup_system(<*.txt>);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Although it seems I can also write `use SystemManager::Action::Generic qw(csay)` once and then just `csay(1,"hello")` instead of `$self->csay(1,"hello")` every time. Would you mind updating your answer to include that information? Although now that I mention it, I would lose the flexibility to overwrite `csay` in the future.

Comment: The variable use is independent of how you choose to define/call `csay`, sure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see (please clarify if I misunderstood) you can just store the `$debug_level` in the parent class:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures);

my $debug_level = shift @ARGV || 0;
my $manager = SystemManager::Action::Backup->new($debug_level);
$manager->backup_system();
exit 0;

package SystemManager::Action::Generic;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures);

sub new ($class, $debug_level) {
    my $pkg = ref($class) || $class ;
    my $self = bless {debug_level => $debug_level}, $pkg;
    return $self;
}
    
sub csay($self, $min_debug_level, $message) {
    if ($self->{debug_level} >= $min_debug_level) { print("$message\n"); }
}

package SystemManager::Action::Backup;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures);

use parent -norequire, "SystemManager::Action::Generic";

sub backup_system($self, @files) {
    $self->csay(1, "Starting backup");
    #$self->prepare_system();
    #$self->csay(1, "Iterating through files");
    #for my $file in (@files) {
    #    $self->csay(2, "Processing $file");
    #    ...
    #}
    #...
}
```